# Calculating norm of ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the norm of an ideal, I know the answer for the below is 2.

$N_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-17})}(\langle 2, 1+\sqrt{17}\rangle)$.

I do realise $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-17})}=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-17}]$, and that $a+b\sqrt{-17} = a-b+b(1+\sqrt{-17})$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. But why the only elements of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-17}]/\langle 2, 1+\sqrt{17}\rangle$ are only $0$ and $1$?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way of calculating these things:

The norm of an ideal $I$ in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-17}]$ is given by $N_{K/\Bbb Q}(I) = (\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-17}] : I)$ (the index of $I$ in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-17}]$).

You have

\begin{align*}\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-17}]/(2, 1 + \sqrt{-17}) &\cong \Bbb Z[X]/(X^2 + 17, 2, 1 + X)\\ &\cong \Bbb F_2[X]/(X^2 - 1, 1 + X)\\ &\cong \Bbb F_2[X]/(1 + X)\\ &\cong \Bbb F_2,\end{align*}

i.e. $N_{K/\Bbb Q}((2, 1 + \sqrt{-17})) = 2$. (Note this also shows that this ideal is a prime ideal).